# Assign a "Group ID" to a recursive cte based on WHERE... IN... in cte

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull information from a multitude of tables. Some of this includes procurement information based on entries that have maintenance records. I have maintenance records (wiirs) that exist on certain physical units. In some cases, many parts (bomlines) have been purchased to do the maintenance.

I am pulling wiir information from one table where WiirId is PK and bomlineid is FK, procurement date from another table via an intermediary table, and trying to group them by WIIRId, finding the earliest procurement info. If there is a way to identify the groups of information coming out of the cte that would be fantastic. I am open to any suggestions.

```
USE emms_srm
-- Declare variables to use to pull data
DECLARE @Start AS datetime, @End AS datetime
SET @Start = '5/1/2014'
SET @End = '5/31/2014'

--Make the table variable to store the sorting list into for this report.
DECLARE @SortList AS TABLE
(
WiirId int NOT NULL
,BomLineId int NOT NULL
)
-- Make table variable to hold the group by list with MIN sc info
DECLARE @GroupList AS TABLE
(
WiirId int NULL
,WiirBomLineId int NULL
,GroupBomLineId int NOT NULL
,SRMSCId int NULL
,SRMSCLineId int NULL
,SRMSCDate datetime NULL
--  ,GroupId int NOT NULL
)
;
--Build list of WIIRs and BomLines for this report.
INSERT INTO @SortList
SELECT DISTINCT vw.WiirId
,vw.BomLineId

FROM dbo.vw_Wiirs AS vw
WHERE (vw.IsComplete = 'True') AND (vw.IsArchived = 'False') AND (IsDeleted = 'False')
AND (vw.CloseoutDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
AND (vw.WiirTypeId = 1) -- New Build (In-House or Make)
AND (vw.WiirSubTypeId IN (1,3,4,7,8,23))
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%R')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%RFM')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%L')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%P')
 ORDER BY vw.WiirId;

--Build list of all children for bomlines from @SortList
WITH prep_cte1(BomLineId, ParentBomLineId, BomId, PartId, Title, Description/*, GroupId*/)
AS ( --Anchor member definition
SELECT bl.BomLineId
    ,bl.ParentBomLineId
    ,bl.BomId
    ,bl.PartId
    ,bl.Title
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') AS 'Description'
    --NEED to assign a group id based on @SortList

FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl

WHERE bl.BomLineId IN (SELECT BomLineId FROM @SortList)
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT bl.BomLineId
    ,bl.ParentBomLineId
    ,bl.BomId
    ,bl.PartId
    ,bl.Title
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
    --NEED to assign a group id based on @SortList

FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl
INNER JOIN prep_cte1 AS p
ON bl.ParentBomLineId = p.BomLineId
)
INSERT INTO @GroupList
--Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT sl.WiirId
,sl.BomLineId
,pc1.BomLineId
,r.SRMSCId
,r.SRMSCLineId
,MIN(r.SRMSCDate)
--  ,pc1.GroupId

FROM prep_cte1 AS pc1
LEFT JOIN dbo.ShoppingLineItems AS sli
ON pc1.BomLineId = sli.BomLineId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Requisitions AS r
ON sli.RequisitionId = r.RequisitionId
LEFT JOIN @SortList AS sl
ON pc1.BomLineId = sl.BomLineId

GROUP BY /*pc1.GroupId,*/ sl.WiirId, sl.BomLineId, pc1.BomLineId, r.SRMSCId, r.SRMSCLineId

ORDER BY sl.WiirId;

SELECT *
FROM @GroupList
--should return the 118 rows from @SortList with the SRMSC information based on the group by
```

Addition: I am trying to build the example in SQLFiddle, but this is my first time using it. As for the existing question, the "GroupId" I'm trying to create will lie within the cte, I hope. Basically the @SortList returns 118 rows, each with a unique WiirId and a unique BomLineId. The BomLines table also has unique BomLineId values, but also houses a self-referential "ParentBomLineId" field. The cte is supposed to pull all levels of the chilren in dbo.BomLines, but I need to have the @SortList.WiirId or @SortList.BomLineId assigned to all of the children so I can group by one of those values, so I know the children all belong to that WiirId or WiirBomLineId. Currently the CTE returns 2500+ rows, but only the original 118 have a non-null value in @SortList.WiirId or @SortList.BomLineId

Once we have the 2500+ rows with GroupId, I then retrieve procurement information from two tables (linked via two different tables), where I retrieve earliest shopping cart from one table, and last purchase order received from another, within specific WIIR groups. So, each of the original 118 lines should report out with the MIN(SRMSCDate) and MAX(FlashDate) for the group of BomLines that falls underneath it (out of the 2500+ retrieved by the CTE).

Comment: Posted an answer, but think it was not what you were looking for.  What is GroupId grouping, exactly?  What do want it to identify which is not being identified already?  Like do you want the recursion level in the cte or something?

Comment: If it is possible to post some input and expected output data either on the question or on sqlfiddle.com, it will be fantastic!

Comment: I have added some content for clarity. My apologies for the delay between posts.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to have an ID for the level of recursion.  If it's that, this will work for you:

```
--Build list of all children for bomlines from @SortList
WITH prep_cte1(BomLineId, ParentBomLineId, BomId, PartId, Title, Description, GroupId)
AS ( --Anchor member definition
    SELECT bl.BomLineId
        ,bl.ParentBomLineId
        ,bl.BomId
        ,bl.PartId
        ,bl.Title
        ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') AS 'Description'
        ,1 AS GroupID

    FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl INNER JOIN @SortList sl
         ON bi.BomLineID = sl.BomLineID

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT bl.BomLineId
        ,bl.ParentBomLineId
        ,bl.BomId
        ,bl.PartId
        ,bl.Title
        ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
        ,p.GroupId + 1

    FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl
    INNER JOIN prep_cte1 AS p
    ON bl.ParentBomLineId = p.BomLineId
)
```

Just seeding a value of 1 in first part of the cte and adding 1 to it on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes have been made to the code to select a GroupId.

1.JOINs with @SortList have been introduced within prep_cte1 to ensure that only the BomLineId on @SortList are selected.

2.In the final INSERT-SELECT statement, `sl.WiirId + '-' + sl.BomLineId` is selected as the GroupId, which uniquely identifies each group.

**Revised code**:

```
USE emms_srm
-- Declare variables to use to pull data
DECLARE @Start AS datetime, @End AS datetime
SET @Start = '5/1/2014'
SET @End = '5/31/2014'

--Make the table variable to store the sorting list into for this report.
DECLARE @SortList AS TABLE
(
WiirId int NOT NULL
,BomLineId int NOT NULL
)
-- Make table variable to hold the group by list with MIN sc info
DECLARE @GroupList AS TABLE
(
WiirId int NULL
,WiirBomLineId int NULL
,GroupBomLineId int NOT NULL
,SRMSCId int NULL
,SRMSCLineId int NULL
,SRMSCDate datetime NULL
--  ,GroupId int NOT NULL
)
;
--Build list of WIIRs and BomLines for this report.
INSERT INTO @SortList
SELECT DISTINCT vw.WiirId
,vw.BomLineId
FROM dbo.vw_Wiirs AS vw
WHERE (vw.IsComplete = 'True') AND (vw.IsArchived = 'False') AND (IsDeleted = 'False')
AND (vw.CloseoutDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
AND (vw.WiirTypeId = 1) -- New Build (In-House or Make)
AND (vw.WiirSubTypeId IN (1,3,4,7,8,23))
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%R')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%RFM')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%L')
AND (vw.PartNumber NOT LIKE '%P')
ORDER BY vw.WiirId;

--Build list of all children for bomlines from @SortList
WITH prep_cte1(BomLineId, ParentBomLineId, BomId, PartId, Title, Description/*, GroupId*/)
AS ( --Anchor member definition
SELECT bl.BomLineId
    ,bl.ParentBomLineId
    ,bl.BomId
    ,bl.PartId
    ,bl.Title
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') AS 'Description'
FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl
INNER JOIN @SortList sl ON bl.BomLineId = sl.BomLineId
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT bl.BomLineId
    ,bl.ParentBomLineId
    ,bl.BomId
    ,bl.PartId
    ,bl.Title
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(bl.Description,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
    --NEED to assign a group id based on @SortList

FROM dbo.BomLines AS bl
INNER JOIN prep_cte1 AS p
ON bl.ParentBomLineId = p.BomLineId
INNER JOIN @SortList sl ON bl.BomLineId = sl.BomLineId
)
INSERT INTO @GroupList
--Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT sl.WiirId
,sl.BomLineId
,pc1.BomLineId
,r.SRMSCId
,r.SRMSCLineId
,MIN(r.SRMSCDate)
--  ,pc1.GroupId
,sl.WiirId + '-' + sl.BomLineId GroupId
FROM prep_cte1 AS pc1
LEFT JOIN dbo.ShoppingLineItems AS sli
ON pc1.BomLineId = sli.BomLineId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Requisitions AS r
ON sli.RequisitionId = r.RequisitionId
LEFT JOIN @SortList AS sl
ON pc1.BomLineId = sl.BomLineId

GROUP BY /*pc1.GroupId,*/ sl.WiirId, sl.BomLineId, pc1.BomLineId, r.SRMSCId, r.SRMSCLineId, sl.WiirId + '-' + sl.BomLineId

ORDER BY sl.WiirId;

SELECT *
FROM @GroupList
--should return the 118 rows from @SortList with the SRMSC information based on the group by
```

Comment: Hi.  Performance-wise, I think the JOIN is better than the WHERE...IN, so I agree with you on that.  But I don't think OP couldn't figure out how to concatenate two values in the final query, both values were already available prior to your edits and the JOIN in the cte did not affect this.  I think OP is looking for a value which can only be calc'd in the cte, for each iteration through.  Anyway, we won't know for sure until he comments.  Wait and see, I guess.

Comment: @VBlades Yeah, I agree. We need to clearly know what the GroupId should look like.